# Will adding db.index=True to a Field in my Django Model help if there is no index on that field in the original db

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I am reading [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques) and it says you should add indexes to fields that you frequently query using `filter()`, `exclude()`, `order_by()`.

I agree with the statement, but will this addition really help if there is no index on the actual database?

Answer (score 3):

Adding [`db_index = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index) to a field and then running [`makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) will generate a migration that adds an appropriate index to your database when [applied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate).